# class TickerProviderStateMixin undefined under flutter v1.0

Tags: flutter

As flutter has released the stable version, i upgraded the sdk and tried to run the former project which is programmed with verison 0.8;
However, some of important classes or mixin (TickerProviderStateMixin, SingleTickerProviderStateMixin) marked as undefined by VSCode.

Error Screen Shot:

[image: Screen Shot]

Did i miss anything or these two classes has been deprecated in the latest version?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#ways-to-fix might be worth a try to ensure your Flutter install is not corrupted. Also ensure you run `flutter clean`.

Comment: When DartAnalyzer behaves weirdly deleting `~/.dartServer/.analysis-driver/` is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
  implements TickerProviderStateMixin
```

To this :

```
  with TickerProviderStateMixin
```

Comment: no error occurred, the project could also ran normally. However the IDE(VSCode) marked the class with red underline; hover the red underline, the tips indicated "[dart] undefined class TickerProviderStateMixin [undefined_class]";